# Narrow down ruby query if a has many association fits two dfferent queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Okay so, To explain it further, I have two queries:

```
  scope :with_free, lambda {
    variants.joins(:stock)
                .where(
                  stock: { tag: %w[Free] }
                ).distinct
  }

  scope :without_free, lambda {
    variants.joins(:stock)
                .where.not(
                  stock: { tag: %w[Free] }
                ).distinct
  }
```

So, `Variant has_many Stocks`.

My problem is that, if for example:

`Variant 1` has two stocks namely:

- `Stock 1` with tag "Free"
- `Stock 2` with tag "Sale"

another Variant, `Variant 2` which also has 2 stocks:

- `Stock 3` with tag "Free"
- `Stock 4` with tag "Free"

and `Variant 3` which also has 2 stocks:

- `Stock 3` with tag "Sale"
- `Stock 4` with tag "Sale"

when `with_free` is called, it will return `Variant 1` and `Variant 2`. Because they have `Stocks` with `tag: "Free"`

but when I call `without_free` it will return `Variant 1` and `Variant 3`. But my expected output when I call `without_free` should just be `Variant 3` since `Variant 1` has a Stock with `tag == "Free"` but it also has a `Stock` with a `tag != "Free"` that is why it is included

I want to ask if there is a way to do that it checks all the `Stocks` and if there is one that has `tag == "Free"` then it will not be included in the output.

Hope I explained it well :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a scope in Stocks:

```
  scope :free, lambda {
      where(tag: %w[Free])
  }
```

and then use it in Variants:

```
  scope :without_free, lambda {
    joins(:stocks)
      .where.not(
      stocks:  Stock.free
    ).distinct
  }
```